# text-transform, javascript, other tom-foolery happening when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been tinkering with a button hover state and some VERY basic javascript, but I've run into a few problems.

HERE is my code:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener("click", myfunction());

function myFunction() {
  alert("HELLO!");
}
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 15px outset #2980b9;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-tranform: uppercase;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#btn:hover {
  border: 10px outset #2980b9;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 26px;

}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

The first problem I have run into is the text-transform will not make the letters on the buttons uppercase, no clue why.

Second, when the buttons are hovered over there is a brief layout adjustment, and all the buttons jump 1 pixel. I have exhausted my brain trying to figure out why.

And lastly, my javascript won't work. I'm am very new to JS so it is most likely some silly syntax error, but I could use the clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing parenthesis form the handler, like `addEventListener("click", myfunction)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few typos - `text-transform` was misspelled; `myFunction` vs `myfunction` (capital F).

You don't want the brackets in the `addEventListener` because you want to register the function, not invoke it here.

Animating `font-size` is causing your jiggles as the browser reflows, so don't do that. You're not really changing the text size much, so you could just omit it. If you really want to, you could try using `transform: scale` instead to scale the text (probably scale it down in the smaller version rather than up in the bigger to avoid it looking pixelly).

You shouldn't have duplicate `id`s - change to using a `class`.

Note that `querySelector()` only returns the first matching element, so if you want to add an event listener to all the buttons, you'll need to use `querySelectorAll()` and iterate through the resulting list. Adding event listeners to multiple elements with a single call like that is more of a jQuery thing.

Fixed version:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'), i;
for (i = 0; i < buttons .length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", myfunction);
}

function myfunction() {
  alert("HELLO!");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 10px outset #2980b9;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: 15px outset #2980b9;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  /*font-size: 26px;*/

}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Figures, it was handful of typo's. Thanks for the fast response. I made the changes to my codepen, and now the alert box only comes up when I refresh the page, not on click. [link](http://codepen.io/tnormington/pen/RPRwKo)

Comment: did you take out the `()` after `myfunction` in the `addEventListener(...)`?

Comment: oh, I didn't spot the link. It works perfectly for me, no alert on refresh, alert when i click the first button.

Comment: Yes, this is my current javascript


document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert("HELLO!");
}

Comment: it's working fine here from your codepen (although as I mentioned in the answer only the first button is clickable). I can't see how you'd now be getting an alert on refresh...

Comment: Ah i see, it only works with the first button. Is there a way to make it work with them all?

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, you need to use `querySelectorAll()`... I guess I'll edit it in